# Angularfire crashes browser when saved

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm doing tests on Angularfire, and every time I save an object to the base, the browser crashes. The screen up is upgraded but I have to stop the execution of the tab and refresh the page so that the browser works properly again.

Would anyone know what might be causing the problem?

[Firefox Crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT1Sm.jpg)

Below is the controller code when saving the object.

```
angular.module("AlbionTrading").controller("indexCtrl", function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {

//Pega objeto direto no Firebase
var ref = firebase.database().ref('AppSettings/');
// download the data into a local object
var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
// synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
// click on `index.html` above to see it used in the DOM!
syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "appName");


//Pega array de objetos no Firebase
var cities = firebase.database().ref('Cities/');
$scope.cities = $firebaseArray(cities);

var posts = firebase.database().ref('Posts/');
$scope.posts = $firebaseArray(posts);


$scope.adicionarPost = function (post) {
console.log(post);
$scope.posts.$add({
    Cidade: post.Cidade.Name,
    Text: post.Text
});
delete $scope.post;
$scope.postForm.$setPristine();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an older version of firebase.. I had the same problem